# SQL server: How to check database has catalog or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, catalog

I am trying to find out whether a database has a catalog or not. I couldn’t find any system stored procedure to perform this task.

I need to find the catalog first then perform Full text search. If a catalog is not found, full text search is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 or later, have you tried the following?

```
select is_fulltext_enabled from sys.databases
```